# Cannot access redux props inside react-navigation v3 tab navigator (getting error this.props.<function_name> is not a function)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am having trouble connecting the tab navigator (from React-Navigation v3) to the redux provider.
So this is how my react-navigation and redux is configured:

```
app/
  /react-redux provider
    /app-container (this is the AppContainer of the main SwitchNavigator)
      /welcome-screen
      /login-screen
      /register-screen
      /home-navigator (this is the TabNavigator that is inside the SwitchNavigator)
```

Home navigator holds the screens to which user is directed to when he logs-in. In the first 3 screends (welcome, login and register) I can access the functions that are "connected" from redux to the screen through standard mapDispatchToProps.

This is the app component:

```
/**
 * Entry point for the app
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";

// redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import main_app_reducer from "./modules/core/reducers/main_app_reducer";

// create redux store
const create_store = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))(createStore);
export const store = create_store(main_app_reducer);

// navigation
import AppContainer from "./modules/core/components/AppNavigator";

import { configure_axios } from "./helpers/axios_config";
configure_axios();

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppContainer />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And then, from there we go to AppContainer:

```
/**
 * this components ensures app navigation so that user can jump from one screen to another
 */

// navigation
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

// screens
import WelcomeScreen from "../screens/WelcomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../../auth/screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "../../auth/screens/RegisterScreen";
import HomeNavigator from "./HomeNavigator";

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    // for users that are not logged in yet
    Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },

    // for logged in users
    HomeNavigator: { screen: HomeNavigator },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

All of the code above works perfectly with no errors, the problem occurs inside the HomeNavigator component that you see below.
This is the HomeNavigator component:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { HomeScreen } from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import { DashboardScreen } from "../screens/DashboardScreen";

const HomeNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
        Dashboard: { screen: DashboardScreen },
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
            return {
                headerTitle: routeName,
            };
        },
    },
);

export default HomeNavigator;
```

NONE of the screens inside the HomeNavigator are connected to Redux altough they are defined THE SAME WAY as the screens inside AppContainer file. For comparison let's see Login screen from AppContainer and Home screen from HomeNavigator:

LoginScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { get_user_servers } from "../actions/core_actions";

export class LoginScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.get_user_servers(); // this function works absolutely fine
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> LoginScreen </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = { get_user_servers };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginScreen);
```

HomeScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { get_user_servers } from "../actions/core_actions";

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.get_user_servers();
// the same function as in LoginScreen but here the function does not work
// I'm getting an error = TypeError: this.props.get_user_servers is not a function (see picture below)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> HomeScreen </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = { get_user_servers };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(HomeScreen);
```

[image: pic]

That function (get_user_servers) is defined properly and it works fine in LoginScreen.

Comment: Forgot to add...
Can someone please help me with this error. It's my first time using react-navigation and I really can't figure out why I have two SAME components but one works and the other doesn't.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone who took their time to help me, in the end it was my mistake that I overlooked. If you check out the third code-block from this question you can see that I import my components like this:

```
import { HomeScreen } from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import { DashboardScreen } from "../screens/DashboardScreen";
```

Which is wrong, I changed that to:

```
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import DashboardScreen from "../screens/DashboardScreen";
```

And now everything works fine, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the same function you're importing, please could you try to check your import of get_user_servers function from both screen : LoginScreen and HomeScreen. According to your code it look like LoginScreen ("../../auth/screens/LoginScreen") and HomeScreen ("../screens/HomeScreen") are not in the same path.

Comment: Hello William,
Yes the function is the same and import paths are correct. 
The first code block in this question is just an illustration of all the "containers" in the app. I have tried to make it easier for you guys to understand my problem.
HomeScreen is located at "modules/core/screens/HomeScreen.js"
LoginScreen is located at "modules/core/screens/LoginScreen.js"
The function is located at "modules/core/actions/core_actions.js"

Comment: I have just found out that function get_user_servers is not in the props of component HomeScreen. See comment I gave to Jonatas below. This is the output of console.log(this.props) in componentWillMount() in HomeScreen.js: https://i.imgur.com/oGIMdFP.png

Comment: I have figured it out, check my answer below. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

As asked above, could check the path of the files, or post it so we can help. Also could you open the remote debugger, and inside the componentWillMount you can put:

```
console.log(this.props)
```

to check if the HomeScreen is geting the function inside props.

Comment: Hello Jonatas, the paths are correct. Interestingly the HomeScreen is not getting the function in the props. This is the output from console.log(this.props) in componentWillMount(): https://i.imgur.com/oGIMdFP.png

Comment: ok, can you try to execute the function as this.get_user_servers(), without props, once this function came like a action not a prop from redux. And if possible just for curiosity, can you show the console.log(this.props) from LoginScreen

Comment: Yes, when I try this.get_user_servers() I get the same error (TypeError: this.get_user_servers is not a function), and this is the output of console.log(this.props) in componentWillMount() in LoginScreen.js: [link](https://i.imgur.com/hsiXzen.png)

Comment: The function runs fine in LoginScreen.js, as you can see the function get_user_servers is in props in LoginScreen, but it is NOT in props in HomeScreen. Clearly there is something wrong with my HomeNavigator configuration.

Comment: I have figured it out, check my answer below. Thanks for the help :)